# Relation between Circular functions and complex numbers.

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers

Does the following equation has a solution?

$$1+e^{\sqrt{-x}}= \sin x$$

I came across it while I was solving

$$\int{2\sin x\cos xdx}$$

Which has multiple solutions as 
$$-\frac{ \cos(2x)}{2}+c_1$$
$$\sin^2(x)+c_2$$
$$-\cos^2(x)+c_3$$

I was checking for value of $c_3$ for which it has a solution equal for which $c_2=0$. I got that equation.

Please help!

Comment: An indefinite integral of a function in one variable only needs one constant of integration.

Comment: @aschepler Why does it have three solution?

Comment: Those are all equivalent solutions, plus or minus a constant which can be absorbed into the $c$ constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how you got that equation from the integral you're trying to solve, but working out that equation, use that:
$$\sin(x)=\Im(e^{ix})=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2}$$